# How to determine the DSL-speed of a wireless modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

This seems like it should be simple. However, modem-routers don't always have their *modem* speeds mentioned in their specifications.

For example - [this TP-LINK router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0086UK72C) on Amazon. It's [specifications' page](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8961ND.html#specifications)  doesn't mention what is its modem's speed. The *wireless* can work up to 300 Mbps. But what about the DSL? How do I find *that* out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find out by looking up the DSL standards that the modem supports. DSL standards give you a theoretical maximum speed the link can offer. Note that there are different variants of DSL, such as ADSL and VDSL.

A list of ADSL standards is [available on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line#ADSL_standards), for example. You'll find [VDSL2 speeds here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-high-bit-rate_digital_subscriber_line_2).

Of course, in reality, those speeds may be lower due to various influence factors, most importantly the distance between your modem and the exchange. Also, the carrier may artifically lower your connection speed.

Comment: Thanks. +1. That looks very good. Except... Wikipedia caps out at `ITU G.992.5 Annex M` (24 Mbps). The modem I mentioned also has `ITU-T G.994.1 (G.hs)` and `ITU-T G.995.1` . Any idea where I can find the speeds for those?

Comment: @ispiro: It seems that both are just handshake protocols, don't directly determine the link speed. (Not entirely sure though.)

Comment: @ispiro As grawity said, those don't have speeds. They "provide a flexible mechanism for Digital Subscriber Line (DSL) transceivers
to exchange capabilities and to select a common mode of operation".

Comment: @slhck Hmmmm. So the question returns. It seems there's no way to know if a modem will support 100Mbps connections.

Comment: @grawity (See my previous comment.)

Comment: @ispiro You never said anything about 100 MBit/s. ADSL and its variants cannot do that. You need VDSL2 support, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-high-bit-rate_digital_subscriber_line_2).

Comment: @slhck Thanks. I thought ADSL was a general term which includes all speeds. So it seems that though this router (and others like it) can support 300 Mbps connections between  computers in your home, they won't support speeds above around 50 Mbps for an internet connection. Not what a consumer would expect! Thanks again.

Comment: @ispiro Yes, it seems so. You may not even be able to connect at all—but I'm not sure about how backwards compatible DSL is in that regard.

Comment: +1 for including _Also, the carrier may artifically lower your connection speed._ which should also be read to mean 'you might be paying less for a speed limit.'

Answer (score 0):

I have DSL and i would just run the  speedtest.net by ookla. This may not give you your modem capability max, but will give you the speed your receiving and sending data through your combined connections,